# How to set up a MySQL connection through a reverse ssh tunnel?

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel

I have a MySQL server running on a hard to reach machine. It is behind a firewall which I have no control over and I can only ssh to it from a specific host. However, I need to expose the MySQL server, in this example to my laptop. I have set up a Raspberry Pi which I have full control of. This is my setup:

(a) laptop --> (b) RPi <-- (c) Server running MySQL

I can ssh from c to b, but not directly from b to c, so my idea was to set up a reverse tunnel from c to b,

```
ssh -R *:3306:localhost:3306 pi@RPi
```

and then, from my laptop, do

```
mysql -h RPi -p 3306
```

This, however, does not work. Even if I ssh to RPi and do

```
mysql -h localhost -p 3306
```

it fails (ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'), so I guess the tunnel isn't working. The weird thing is, that if I do this on the server (c):

```
 ssh -R 2200:localhost:22 pi@RPi
```

then ssh -p 2200 pi@localhost works.
Is there some reason why MySQL shouldn't work through a tunnel? Or is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried connecting to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: This helped a bit: Now I can connect to mysql on the server from the pi, mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3306, but still not from my laptop.

Comment: and by setting GatewayPorts to 'yes' on the RPi, it works.